# Windows Embedded Compact 7 SDK

Tags: windows-ce

Does Microsoft deliver a generic Windows Embedded Compact 7 SDK?

I'm aware that I in principle should get the SDK from the manufacturer of the hardware who would use their Platform builder to create it. But when making software that's supposed to be used by many different customers on a lot of different CE 7 hardware, it's impossible.

The SDK that is provided by Microsoft for CE 5 works very well on most CE 5 (6 and 7) devices so it seems like it is possible to have an (almost) generic SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the "standard SDK" os component is not supported on CE 6,7 and 8(2013) and this prevents device manufacturers from providing a minimum set of features covered by it.
This means that you'll have to build your own SDK to develop a generic app, including all the features you need (and with no grants that it will work on a specific device) or to rebuild the app for each device you target (you may discover if it will lack some components, but may be hard to maintain if you target a large number of different platforms).
If you don't want to build your own images and SDKs, Toradex provides quite generic SDKs for ARM (covering the components we put in our image that are more or less those in the core licenses).

Comment: Thanks.That was what I feared ;-) 
The Toradex SDK license agreement seems prohibitive: 
a.   Use. The software license is permanently assigned to the device with which you acquired the software. You may use the software on the device only.
As I understand it, you can only use the software with Toradex hardware.

Comment: Actually this is relative to the OS image, SDK should be used with our modules, of course, but are not bounded with HW.